# how to enable debugging mode using database in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I am using magento 1.6, I am getting error on all pages

```
"404 error: Page not found."
```

I am even not able to open admin, have upgraded it from 1.5 to 1.6

Can anyone help , what should I do.

Please provide query to enable bedug mode from database so that I can see what is happening as I can't access admin.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. check file permissions and mode rewrite
2. uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1)
3. check step by step with xdebug
4. use base_url/index.php/admin (if it work, then configure .htaccess)